# Can't determine any concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display concurrency on my console to check wheter i use the child_process libary right. To do this i got those two modules:

test.js

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

const child1 = fork('./newModule', ['child1']);
console.log('now1');
const child2 = fork('./newModule', ['child2']);
console.log('now2');

child1.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
console.log('now3');
child2.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

newModule.js

```
(function(cb) {

        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            process.send(process.argv[2] + ' ' + i);
        }
        process.exit();

}());
```

But the output on my console is:

```
now1
now2
now3
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
child2 0
child2 1
child2 2
child2 3
child2 4
child2 5
child2 6
child2 7
child2 8
child2 9
child2 10
child2 11
child2 12
child2 13
child2 14
child2 15
child2 16
child2 17
child2 18
child2 19
child2 20
child2 21
child2 22
child2 23
child2 24
child2 25
child2 26
child2 27
child2 28
child2 29
child2 30
child2 31
child2 32
child2 33
child2 34
child2 35
child2 36
child2 37
child2 38
child2 39
child2 40
child2 41
child2 42
child2 43
child2 44
child2 45
child2 46
child2 47
child2 48
child2 49
child1 0
child1 1
child1 2
child1 3
child1 4
child1 5
child1 6
child1 7
child1 8
child1 9
child1 10
child1 11
child1 12
child1 13
child1 14
child1 15
child1 16
child1 17
child1 18
child1 19
child1 20
child1 21
child1 22
child1 23
child1 24
child1 25
child1 26
child1 27
child1 28
child1 29
child1 30
child1 31
child1 32
child1 33
child1 34
child1 35
child1 36
child1 37
child1 38
child1 39
child1 40
child1 41
child1 42
child1 43
child1 44
child1 45
child1 46
child1 47
child1 48
child1 49
```

Instead i was expecting to have something like:

```
now1
now2
now3
1
child1 1
child2 1
2
child1 2
child2 2
...
```

or

```
now1
now2
now3
child1 1
child2 1
child1 2
child2 2
...
1
2
...
```

Whats the reason for this? Is there no concurrency or am I just displaying it wrong?

Comment: this code works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a `for` loop, you keep the process doing **just that** and nothing else - it won't even allow Node.js to flush the message to the parent process because the JavaScript thread (and there can be only one JS thread) is busy looping through that `for` loop.

You do this in all processes - in the parent process, and in both of the child processes. This means that somewhere, under the hood, the messages to the console cannot be really sent to the parent process or to `stdout` stream because Node.js also implements considerable amount of functionality in JavaScript and since that thread is busy doing your `for` loop it will get executed at the very end of that loop, flushing everything at once. In addition, since you are doing a `for` loop in the parent process, even if the messages were indeed successfully sent to the parent process they would not be processed until the end of your `for` loop because they would be waiting for the JS thread to become available for other work. This is how the event loop works (see below for link).

To prevent this behaviour, you will need to re-implement that loop in some other way - one that would allow Node to perform other work between individual iterations.

There are many tutorials how to do this elsewhere. The things you will want to look for are a general overview of Node's [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) and [`setImmediate()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/timers.html#timers_class_immediate) (to schedule work to be done in next event loop).